# using React can I prevent sending empty strings from my inputs to my mongodb database during update?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have inputs that take in information that is set to the state. The states initial values is set to empty strings. none of the inputs are required inputs so some may remain blank I then send the inputted information to the the API but that may send possible empty strings which would replaces information that I don't want to update.
I tried setting the initial states to undefined but i got the uncontrolled inputs error because I know undefined values would not be accepted in my database.

I have thought about maybe creating an array and pushing only the values that aren't equal to an empty string  into it and then sending the array to the API.

```
 import React from "react";
import API from "../../utils/API";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { storage } from "../../config/fire";

class ProfileEditor extends React.Component {
    state = {

        image: null,
        url: "",
        isActive: false,

        emailaddress: "",
        password: "",
        confirm: "",
        screenName: "",
        securityQuestion: "",
        securityAnswer: "",
        birthDate: "",
        gender: "",
        phoneNumber: "",
        cityState: "",
        userPic: "",

    }


    handleChange = e => {


        this.setState({
            [e.target.name]: e.target.value
        });
    };



    updateProfile = id => {






        if (this.state.password.length > 0 && this.state.password.length < 6) {
            alert(
                `Choose a more secure password `
            );
        } else if (this.state.password !== this.state.confirm) {
            alert("You Passwords do not match");
        } else {






            API.updateEditProfile(id, {


                password: this.state.password,
                screenName: this.state.screenName,
                securityQuestion: this.state.securityQuestion,
                securityAnswer: this.state.securityAnswer,
                birthDate: this.state.birthDate,
                gender: this.state.gender,
                phoneNumber: this.state.phoneNumber,
                cityState: this.state.cityState,
                userPic: this.state.url
            })
                .then(function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
                })
                .catch(err => console.log(err));

                document.getElementById("profileForm").reset();
        }


    }







    handleImageSelected = event => {
        this.uploadClick()
        if (event.target.files[0]) {
            const image = event.target.files[0];
            this.setState(() => ({ image }));
        }



    }


    handleUpload = () => {
        const fullName = this.props.userInfo.firstname + "_" + this.props.userInfo.lastname;
        const { image } = this.state;
        const uploadTask = storage.ref(fullName + "/" + image.name).put(image);
        uploadTask.on("state_changed",
            (snapshot) => {
                const progress = Math.round((snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100);
                this.setState({ progress: progress })
            },
            (error) => {
                console.log(error);
            },
            () => {
                storage.ref(fullName).child(image.name).getDownloadURL()
                    .then(url => {
                        this.setState({ url: url });
                        console.log(url)
                    })
            });
    }

    uploadClick = () => {

        this.setState({ isActive: !this.state.isActive })
    };










    render() {
        const fullName = this.props.userInfo.firstname + " " + this.props.userInfo.lastname
        const user = this.props.userInfo
        console.log(this.props.userInfo.userPic)
        return (

            <div className="contentArea ">
                <div className="profile-container">
                    <div className="profile-image">
                        <img src={this.props.userInfo.userPic} />
                    </div>
                    <div className="profile-info">
                        {fullName}
                    </div>

                    <section className="editProfile">
                        <div className="unchangeable">Name:  {fullName} </div>
                        <div className="unchangeable">Email: {this.props.userInfo.emailaddress}</div>
                        <form id="profileForm">
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" placeholder="Password" name="password" ref="password" className="editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.confirm} onChange={this.handleChange} type="password" placeholder="confirm password" name="confirm" ref="confirmPassword" className="editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.securityQuestion} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="security question" name="securityQuestion" ref="securityQuestion" className="editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.securityAnswer} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="Answer to security question" name="securityAnswer" ref="securityAnswer" className="editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.screenName} onChange={this.handleChange} placeholder="screen name" name="screenName" className="editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.birthDate} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="birth date" name="birthDate" className="editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.Gender} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="gender" name="gender" className=" editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.phoneNumber} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="phone number" name="phoneNumber" className=" editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs">
                                <input value={this.state.cityState} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="city/state" name="cityState" className=" editInput" />
                            </div>
                            <div className="profileInputs"> Are you in a Relationship?
                    <input value={this.state.Gender} onChange={this.handleChange} type="text" placeholder="" name="gender" className=" editInput" />
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </section>

                    <section className="feed ">
                        <div className="avatar">
                            <div className="avatarsect">
                                Upload Avatar
                        </div>
                            <input type="file" style={{ display: "none" }} onChange={this.handleImageSelected} ref={fileInput => this.fileInput = fileInput} />
                            <img className={this.state.isActive ? "uploadReady active" : "uploadReady"} src={this.state.url} alt="previewupload" height="40" width="50" />

                            <progress className={this.state.isActive ? "uploadReady active" : "uploadReady"} value={this.state.progress} max="100" />
                            <button className={this.state.isActive ? "uploadReady active" : "uploadReady"} onClick={this.handleUpload}>Upload</button>
                            <span className={this.state.isActive ? "uploadReady active" : "uploadReady"}></span>
                            <button type="button" className="button photo" onClick={() => this.fileInput.click()}><i class="fas fa-camera-retro"></i></button>


                        </div>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <div className="btnDiv">
                            <button onClick={() => this.updateProfile(this.props.userInfo.user_ID)} className="updateProfileBtn"> Update Profile</button>
                        </div>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                        <br></br>
                    </section>


                </div>

            </div>
        );
    }



}



export default ProfileEditor;

my Api

  updateEditProfile:function(id,userData) {
    console.log(userData)
    console.log(id)
    return axios.put("/api/usersData/" +id, userData);

  },
```

my route and controller

```
router.route("/")
  .post(usersDataController.findUserinfo)
  .put(usersDataController.update)
  router.route("/:id")
  .put(usersDataController.updateByID);

 updateByID: function(req, res) {
    console.log(res)
    db.usersData
      .findByIdAndUpdate({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body,{new:true})
      .then(dbModel => res.json(dbModel))
      .catch(err => res.status(422).json(err));
  },
```

Comment: the data is sent to the api in the updateEditProfile function but I added the API, the route and controller